# Why do I get an error when I call int(input()) where input is decimal (eg. '87.94')?

Tags: python, math, multiplication

I'm a programming newbie having difficulty with Python multiplication. I have code like this:

```
def getPriceDiscount():
    price = int(input())
    if price > 3000:
        priceDiscount = price * 0.6
        return priceDiscount
    else:
        return price
```

But when I execute it and type an input which is a decimal number like 87.94, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '87.94'
```

Isn't the `int()` method able to convert the string '87.94' into a number allowing me to multiply it by 0.6? What should I do to perform that conversion?

I'm using Python 3.2.2.

Comment: If you're doing currency calculations, you should look into using the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module, due the [limitations of floating point arithmetic](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `int` (short for "integer") is a whole number. A `float` (short for "floating-point number") is a number with a decimal point.

`int()` returns an `int` created from its input argument. You can use it to convert a string like `"15"` into the `int` `15`, or a `float` like `12.059` into the `int` `12`.

`float()` returns a `float` created from its input argument. You can use it to convert a string like `"10.5"` into the `float` `10.5`, or even an `int` like `12` into the `float` `12.0`.

If you want to force `price` to be an integer, but you want to accept a floating point number as typed input, you need to make the input a `float` first, then convert it with `int()`:

```
price = int(float(input())
```

Note that if you multiply an `int` by a `float` such as your discount factor, the result will be a `float`.

Also note that my example above doesn't round the number -- it just truncates the stuff after the decimal point. For example, if the input is `"0.6"` then `price` will end up being `0`. Not what you want? Then you'll need to use the `round()` function on the `float` first.

```
price = int(round(float(input()))
```

If you intended to use floating point calculations (which makes sense if we're talking about a commodity price), then don't perform the `int` conversion. Just use `float`. You may still want to do some rounding. If you want to round to 2 decimal places, you can call round with the second argument as `2`:

```
price = round(float(input()),2)
```

Finally, you might want to look into [Python's `decimal` module](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html), since there are limitations when using floating point numbers. See here for more information: http://docs.python.org/tutorial/floatingpoint.html

Comment: Thank you very much, you dissected my possibilities of doubt and even brought some information that I would look for (round ()).

Answer (score 6):

Actually, you CAN pass a floating point value to `int()`. In that case `int()` just rounds the number down and converts that value to an integer type.

However, what you're doing when you call `int("87.94")` is passing a string resembling a decimal point value to `int()`. `int()` can't directly convert from such a string to an integer. You hence must use `float()`, which can convert from strings to floats.

Comment: Thank you very much, your explanation made ​​me understand exactly my mistake and now I am a programmer a little better.

Answer (score 3):

You can't pass a string with a decimal point to `int()`. You can use `float()` instead. If you want  only the integral part i.e. to truncate the `.94` in `87.94`, you can do `int(float('87.94'))`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're trying to do **two convertions at a time, and one of them is implicit**.

The following will work because there's an obvious way to transfrom the number '87' to the integer 87.

```
>>> int('87')
87
```

And for the same reason, the following will work too:

```
>>> float('87')
87.0
>>> float('87.94')
87.94
>>> int(87.94)
87
```

Keep in mind what's been said and look at the difference between:

```
>>> int(float('87.94'))
87
```

and

```
>>> int('87.94')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '87.94'
```

As you see the problem is that you're implying a `float()` conversion before passing to `int()`, but how could the compiler guess that? There are plenty of available working conversions for the string '87.94'. Should the compiler tried them all before finding out which onw will work with `int`? And what if there are two or more that will return something that will work with integer?

Examples:

```
>>> int(hash('87.94'))
4165905645189346193
>>> int(id('87.94'))
22325264
>>> int(max('87.94'))
9
>>> int(input('87.94'))
87.94111
111
```

**Should the compiler choose `float()` for you?**
I don't think so: [Explicit is better than implicit](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/).

---

Anyway if you are going to use that number to perform a multiplication with a float number `0.6`. You could directly convert it to a [`float()`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html#float).

Change this line:

```
price = int(input())
```

with:

```
price = float(input())
```

And everything will be ok.

Also, the operation you are presenting in your example is a *multiplication*, not a *division*. In case you might be interested, there is the floor division `//` that will return an integer insted of a float. Take a look at [PEP238](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/) for more informations about this.

Answer (score 1):

```
def getPriceDiscount():
    while True:
        try:
            price, percent = float(input()), 0.6
            break
        except ValueError:
            continue
    return price * percent if price > 3000 else price

print(getPriceDiscount())
```

Comment: @Series8217 It is obvious, it is obvious that the user is a brain :)

Comment: The OP is a newbie and is still learning how to troubleshoot errors. The `coerce` error is not even very descriptive: `TypeError: number coercion failed`.